# Python GreasePencilGrid Usage

Tags: python

I was going through the Blender Python Documentation and i came across the class [bpy.types.GreasePencilGrid](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GreasePencilGrid.html). I am not sure how to use it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special construct belonging to [bpy.types.GreasePencil](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GreasePencil.html#bpy.types.GreasePencil.grid).

It helps the user define a canvas that is displayed as an overlay in the 3D viewport. Its properties can be tweaked per-object.

You can enable the canvas display in the viewport overlays.

[image]

By default it looks like this

[image]

You can see these properties by going into the *Viewport Display* subpanel in the grease pencil data properties.

[image]

Here's how you use it with the API :

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]  # This is of type bpy.types.Object
gp = obj.data  # bpy.types.GreasePencil
grid = gp.grid  # bpy.types.GreasePencilGrid
grid.color = (1, 0, 0)
grid.lines = 8
grid.scale = (0.5, 2)
grid.offset = (0.5, 0.5)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks